# How to delete multiple rows in C# using a SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have code for deleting a row in C# using a `SqlCommand`. But I want to delete multiple rows. Can anyone help me with this? I am new to C#.

This is my code - please help. Thank you in advance.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGrid1.SelectedRows)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DDBULK10\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MasterList; Integrated Security = True";
                if (dr.Index > 0)
                {
                    int selectedIndex = dataGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

                    int rowID = int.Parse(dataGrid1[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
                    string sql = "DELETE FROM ActiveUser WHERE EmpId = @EmpId";

                    SqlCommand deleteRecord = new SqlCommand();
                    deleteRecord.Connection = con;
                    deleteRecord.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    deleteRecord.CommandText = sql;

                    SqlParameter RowParameter = new SqlParameter();
                    RowParameter.ParameterName = "@EmpId";
                    RowParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                    RowParameter.IsNullable = false;
                    RowParameter.Value = rowID;

                    deleteRecord.Parameters.Add(RowParameter);

                    deleteRecord.Connection.Open();

                    deleteRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //deleteRecord.Connection.Close();

                    MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Deleted");

                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ActiveUser", con);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
                }

                else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    this.Refresh();
                }
            }
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly? I could imagine that you either wrap your statement code in a for each block to execute multiple deletes (very slow), or that you create an array of all those IDs that should be deleted and cast this array into a list an use SQL's `in (3, 4, 5,)` in the where clause

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block (even if an exception occurred). ExecuteNonQuery returns how many rows are affected, if you want to know whether it did what you wanted.

Comment: You can pass multiple.ids to the query using a table value parameter.

Comment: is it from a grid or datatable?

Comment: can you check with deleteRecord.ExecuteQuery(); ? Actually you have written a query that will delete multiple rows from the table according to a particular UserID

Comment: @Jan i have tried to wrap my code in a foreach block but the result is still the same. Can you help which part has a problem?

Comment: @Gie, use the “SelecteRows” foreach to create an array of the IDs. Then follow the approach suggested by Jan. This way you will execute the DB operation only once. Bharati has already added that as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a comma separated userid list like -

```
string strUserIds = string.Empty();
for(int i=0; i<dataGrid.Count;i++)
{
  strUserIds = strUserIds +","+ dataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
}
--Remove last unwanted comma from strUserIds 
then execute sql query as "DELETE FROM EmployeeTbl WHERE  UserID in (" + strUserIds + ")"
```

This will delete multiple records from table.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Make some changes in Your Coding !**

1. Delete All Selected Rows
2. Run Your select * from ActiveUser

   public void deldata()
       {
           foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGrid1.SelectedRows)
           {
               SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
               con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DDBULK10\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MasterList; Integrated Security = True";
               if (dr.Index > 0)
               {
                   int selectedIndex = dataGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

   ```
               int rowID = int.Parse(dataGrid1[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
               string sql = "DELETE FROM ActiveUser WHERE EmpId = @EmpId";

               SqlCommand deleteRecord = new SqlCommand();
               deleteRecord.Connection = con;
               deleteRecord.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
               deleteRecord.CommandText = sql;

               SqlParameter RowParameter = new SqlParameter();
               RowParameter.ParameterName = "@EmpId";
               RowParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
               RowParameter.IsNullable = false;
               RowParameter.Value = rowID;

               deleteRecord.Parameters.Add(RowParameter);

               deleteRecord.Connection.Open();

               deleteRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();

               //deleteRecord.Connection.Close();

               MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Deleted");


           }

           else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
           {
               this.Refresh();
           }
       }
   }
   public void showdata()
   {
       SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ActiveUser", con);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       sda.Fill(dt);
       dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this; i didn't test the code but it should work if you create the parameters you need, before running code you have to create a [type table, please see the link for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

```
 using (connection)
        {
            string sql ="Delete from YourTable t join @yourTypeTable i on t.id = i.Id:";

            SqlCommand deleteCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            SqlParameter tvpParam = deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourTypeTable", yourIdList);
            tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.yourTypeTable";

            deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```